# COUNT in LEFT JOIN returning duplicated value

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I've the following tables (example):

**users**:

```
id | user | photo   | joined | country
1  | Igor | abc.jpg | 2015   | Brazil
2  | John | cga.png | 2014   | USA
3  | Lucas| hes.jpg | 2016   | Japan
```

**posts** (see that there are two lines with `author = Igor` and `ft = 2` and one line with `author = Igor` and `ft = 3` and Igor have three posts):

```
id | author | content | date | ft (2 = photos and 3 = videos)
1  | Igor   | hi      | 2016 | 2
2  | Igor   | hello   | 2016 | 3
3  | John   | hehehe  | 2016 | 2
4  | Igor   | huhuhuh | 2016 | 2
5  | Lucas  | lol     | 2016 | 3
```

**friendship** (when `status = 2` means that they are friends):

```
id | friend1 | friend2 | status
1  | Igor    | Lucas   | 2
2  | Lucas   | John    | 2
3  | John    | Igor    | 2
```

And I want to do a `COUNT` of **posts** with `ft = 2` and a `COUNT` of friends (`status = 2`) according to the currently logged user (Igor, in this case).

So, I do (assuming that the current user logged in is **Igor**):

```
SELECT photo, joined, country, sum(CASE WHEN ft = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS numPhotos, sum(CASE WHEN ft = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS numVideos
FROM users
LEFT JOIN posts
ON users.user = posts.author
WHERE users.user = 'Igor'
GROUP BY users.user
LIMIT 1
```

And when I check on a `foreach`, the data is correct:
`numPhotos = 2` and `numVideos = 1`.

But, I want to select too the number of friends, so, I do:

```
SELECT photo, joined, country, sum(CASE WHEN ft = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS numPhotos, sum(CASE WHEN ft = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS numVideos, count(friendship.status) AS numFriends
FROM users
LEFT JOIN posts
ON users.user = posts.author
LEFT JOIN friendship
ON (users.user = friend1 OR users.user = friend2) AND friendship.status = 2
WHERE users.user = 'Igor'
GROUP BY users.user
LIMIT 1
```

But, the output is:
`numPhotos = 4`, `numVideos = 2` and `numFriends = 6`.

In other words, he is duplicating all results but in `numFriends` he's taking the total of posts of Igor (3) and duplicating the value too. And if I change `count(friendship.status)` to `sum(friendship.status)` the output is:
`numPhotos = 4`, `numVideos = 2` and `numFriends = 18` (triples the `numFriends`).

I tried too with `count(distinct friendship.status)` and the result is:
`numPhotos = 4`, `numVideos = 2` and `numFriends = 1` (duplicates the values again as well as return the wrong value 1 for `numFriends` that should be 2 knowing he has two friends).

So, how I can do this? (I'm using MySQL)

**EDIT**:

I changed the `count(distinct friendship.status)` to `count(distinct friendship.id)` and it worked to select the number of friends. But the rest of values (`numPhotos` and `numVideos`) continue duplicated.

I discovered that the problem is in `ON (users.user = friend1 OR users.user = friend2)`, because if I leave only  `ON (users.user = friend1)` or `ON (users.user = friend2)` the output isn't duplicated. I tried too with `ON 'Igor' IN (friend1, friend2) but the result is the same (`numPhotos`and`numVideos` continue duplicated).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the left join may be joining on a one-to-many relationship, which is causing inflated counts.
Since you are only retrieving the counts for 1 user, I suggest using a subquery to retrieve the friendship counts (for retrieving the counts for multiple users, a derived table may be faster than a subquery):

```
SELECT 
    sum(ft = 2) AS numPhotos, 
    sum(ft = 3) AS numVideos,
    (select count(*) from friendships f
    where (friend1 = users.user 
    or friend2 = users.user)
    and status = 2) as friendship_count
FROM users
LEFT JOIN posts
ON users.user = posts.author
WHERE users.user = 'Igor'
```

Note that I removed the `group by` because `users.user` is already in the where clause, which means there is only 1 group.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `count(distinct friendship.status)`, try using `count(distinct friendship.id)`. That should give you the number of unique friends. Counting distinct statuses doesn't work because all the statuses will be 2 by definition, so there is only one distinct value.

Comment: It works! But the rest of values (`numPhotos` and `numVideos`) continue duplicate .